# MPAndroidChart can't show markerview if I add onTouchListener ,if I remove onTouchListener ,markview can show again

Tags: mpandroidchart

I'm using MPAndroidChart and it's very good ,but now I have a problem just like what I described . Besides, my onClick event can be triggered !

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "onChartValueSelectedListener":

```
mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry entry, int i, Highlight highlight) {
            //display msg when value selected
            if (entry == null)
                return;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), entry.getXIndex() + " = " + entry.getVal() + "%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {

        }
    });
```